# What are some examples of asymptotic expansions of integrals displaying the Stokes phenomenon?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

With the term [Stokes phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_phenomenon) we refer to how the asymptotic behaviour of a function can differ in different regions of the complex plane.

What are some examples of asymptotic expansions of functions defined in integral form (i.e. functions defined in a way similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221930/173147) ) in which this phenomenon is easily seen?

Comment: The Stokes phenomenon for the asymptotic for the Airy function can be derived from its integral representation.  This is discussed in detail in Section 4.7 of Miller's *Applied Asymptotic Analysis*.

Comment: Further, most (all?) Laplace/Fourier transforms where the integral converges on a large enough portion of the plane will have this phenomenon.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'm looking for a case in which we are able to derive explicitly the asymptotic expansions in the various areas, so as to be able to actually see phenomenon at work. Do you know an example of this kind?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you can do that for the Airy function.  And what I meant by my second comment was if you write down any function of the form $$f(x) = \int_{-a}^{b} e^{xt}g(t)\,dt,$$ where $g$ is nice enough, then you can do the same by using Watson's lemma (the anti-Stokes line would be the imaginary axis).